# Why when adding a Character Controller to npc the npc is in the air when running the game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Before running the game the npc position on Y is 50 and the npc is on the ground.
After running the game the npc position on Y is change to 51.08

[image: Before running the game the npc position on Y is 50]

After running the game :

[image: After running the game the npc position on Y is 51.08]

How can I keep the npc to be on the ground after adding Character Controller ?

Comment: Add to your question the controller script

Comment: @Lotan I can't find it. It's a component I added to the character but I can't find the script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise the CharacterController's center's `y` to `1.08`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-center.html